# Gspread me devuelve todo el worksheet como strings, independientemente del contenido original de las celdas

Tags: python, string, google-hoja-de-cálculo, formato

estoy dando mis primeros pasos en Python. Jugando con Gspread me sucede que se me abre el worksheet con el contenido de todas las celdas como string, aunque en la planilla original sean valores numéricos, por lo que no me permite hacer operaciones.

Como mantengo el formato original?

Estoy haciendo esto, quizás esté partiendo con el pie izquierdo:

```
# abro la hoja 1 del documento Planilla1
worksheet = gc.open('Planilla1').sheet1
# asigno los valores de la primera linea a la lista values_list
values_list = worksheet.row_values(1)
```

La lista termina siendo una lista de strings, independientemente del formato que le asigne a esas celdas en el documento original Planilla1.
Agradezco cualquier comentario que me guíe en la direccion correcta.

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=row_values#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.row_values) `row_values()` acepta un argumento [`value_render_option`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) que permite configurar la forma en que los valores van a ser interpretados.

Intenta utilizar `FORMATTED_VALUE`, esto permite utilizar el formato configurado en la celda, por lo que si es, por ejemplo, una celda está configurada con formato de moneda o divisas entonces el resultado podría verse así `$1.25`, incluyendo el símbolo de la moneda.

En otro escenario, si utilizaras `UNFORMATTED_VALUE` a pesar de que el formato de la celda fuera moneda o divisas el resultado se vería `1.25` ignorando el símbolo de la moneda.